# pandas, retaining columns when data is empty after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

```
(Pdb) df.head()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [user_id, review_meta_id, rating_type, score, timestamp, user_id_index, review_meta_id_index]
Index: []

(Pdb) df.groupby(['user_id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(M, 'timestamp'))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Can I make second one creates an empty dataframe but with the same column as in the first output?
(primarily to keep interface the same for either cases)

I want something like the following...

```
(Pdb) df.groupby(['user_id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(M, 'timestamp'))
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [user_id, review_meta_id, rating_type, score, timestamp, user_id_index, review_meta_id_index]
Index: []
```

Comment: Maybe you could store `df.columns` as a variable, then reassign `df.columns = x` after the groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use faster alterative solution with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
M = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1] * 5 + [2] * 4,
                   'timestamp':range(9)})
print (df)
   user_id  timestamp
0        1          0
1        1          1
2        1          2
3        1          3
4        1          4
5        2          5
6        2          6
7        2          7
8        2          8

print (df.sort_values(['user_id','timestamp'], ascending=[True, False])
         .groupby('user_id')
         .head(M))

   user_id  timestamp
4        1          4
3        1          3
2        1          2
8        2          8
7        2          7
6        2          6
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_id','timestamp'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [user_id, timestamp]
Index: []

print (df.sort_values(['user_id','timestamp'], ascending=[True, False])
         .groupby('user_id')
         .head(M))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [user_id, timestamp]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks yet again, can you give a bit of info why seemingly same operation results in two different data formats? (I guess it's because `apply` vs `head`?)

Comment: @eugene - exactly, [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is more general, so working different like [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html).